# TypeORM upsert on partial index (indexPredicate)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

I have a Postgres table with a partial index as such

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_unique_index
ON my_table
USING btree (cola, colb)
WHERE deleted = FALSE;
```

If I write a raw query I'm able to do upserts via ON CONFLICT

```
INSERT INTO my_table (cola, colb)
VALUES ('a', 'b')
ON CONFLICT (col_a, col_b) WHERE deleted = FALSE
DO UPDATE SET
  cola = EXCLUDED.cola,
  colb = EXCLUDED.colb;
```

But when I attempt to use typeorm's upsert method I get a typeorm error of 'column (deleted = FALSE) does not exist)

My usage is:

```
this.repo.upsert(
  { cola: 'a', colb: 'b' },
  {
    skipUpdateIfNoValuesChanged: true,
    conflictPaths: ['cola','colb'],
    indexPredicate: 'deleted = FALSE',
   }
)
```

Anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong? Seems like I'm following typeorm docs but unsure why I only get the error using typeorm.

Tried different ways of setting the unique index WHERE clause... In parens, not in parens...

Answer (score 0):

It should be `"deleted" IS FALSE`, note the quotation marks.

There's was a [bug in the implementation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/10191) that had no known workaround, yet the [PR](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/10618) that fixes is has been merged so likely the 0.3.20 version just released contains the fix for the issue you're having.

Comment: This provides information on the subject and indicates that there's NO possible answer at the time. These reviews have no value on their own.